# Create a TypeScript interface template

Tags: typescript, templates, interface

I've noticed a lot of repeats happening as I extends my code base when it comes to creating TypeScript interfaces in my project.

See this:

```
interface IErrorResponse {
  code: number
  message: string
}

// Feature 1
type FEATURE_1_KEYS =
  | 'fetchingActivities'
  | 'fetchingActivityTypes'

interface IFeature1ErrorAction
  extends IErrorResponse {
  key: FEATURE_1_KEYS
}

// Feature 2
type FEATURE_2_KEYS =
  | 'fetchingSomethingElse'
  | 'updatingSomething'

interface IFeature2ErrorAction
  extends IErrorResponse {
  key: FEATURE_2_KEYS
}
```

So current when I use the final `ErrorAction`s (interfaces) here I'd use `IFeature1ErrorAction` and `IFeature2ErrorAction`. My project has a lot of features.

Is there a way to create an `IErrorAction` that's built from my `IErrorResponse` where I just pass in those `FEATURE_KEYS` for the key?

Then I could use it like this `IErrorAction<FEATURE_1_KEYS>`.

This would save a lot of repetition in my development process and I'm certain it can be done, I'm just not sure how.

Essentially the outcome of this interface for `IErrorAction<FEATURE_1_KEYS>` would render the following interface:

```
interface IErrorAction = { // How do I get that `TEMPLATED_KEYS` in there?
  code: number,
  key: TEMPLATED_KEYS,
  message: string
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make the base interface generic, accepting a type parameter that extends `string`:

```
interface IErrorResponse<TFeatures extends string> {
  code: number
  message: string
  key: TFeatures
}

// Feature 1
type FEATURE_1_KEYS =
  | 'fetchingActivities'
  | 'fetchingActivityTypes'

type IFeature1ErrorAction = IErrorResponse<FEATURE_1_KEYS> // 

// Feature 2
type FEATURE_2_KEYS =
  | 'fetchingSomethingElse'
  | 'updatingSomething'

type IFeature2ErrorAction = IErrorResponse<FEATURE_2_KEYS>
```

`IErrorResponse<FEATURE_1_KEYS>` and `IErrorResponse<FEATURE_2_KEYS>` can be aliased as above or you can use them directly.